# How do I specify a Postgresql schema in ScalaQuery?

Tags: scalaquery

I tried, for instance:

```
object WebCache extends Table[(...)]("myschema.mytable") {
  ...
}
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slick now [has this functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13381680/828757):

```
object WebCache extends Table[(...)](Some("myschema"), "mytable") {
  ...
}
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer from the scalaquery mailing list. This is a limitation of ScalaQuery.

> This is not supported at the moment but it should be very easy to add. 
>   I've created https://github.com/szeiger/scala-query/issues/19 for this 
>   issue.